# More compelling way to describe something as "The Next Big Thing"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

What is a more compelling way to say "The next big thing in X".?

It will be describing a technology company that is "disrupting" (also too much of a cliche) the industry.

Comment: The next stupid idiom.

Comment: . . . . Next . . . .

Comment: "The cliche to end all cliches!"

Answer (score 3):

You might describe it as a "game-changer" for the industry.

Answer (score 1):

It's

- the **future** of the industry
- the **Apple*** of the dairy industry

*I've intended this as a comparison to the company Apple, not an apple. That may be clear when written, but not when said.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it is an **advance over current trend** or that **the previous theory will soon come to an end after this discovery of yours**.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the product is [revolutionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary).

> [adjective] causing or relating to a great or complete change

Answer (score 0):

You could say that this thing is a ***seminal development*** or ***seminal advancement***

> ***Seminal:*** highly original and influencing the development of future events:
>   *a seminal artist; seminal ideas*.

Dictionary.com

Alternatively, you could refer to this thing as a ***landmark***, or perhpas ***landmark achievement***

> ***Landmark:*** an event or discovery marking an important stage or turning point in something. *"the vaccine is a landmark in the history of preventive medicine"*

OED