# Single phrase or word for someone who's about to achieve success

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know the single phrase or word used for someone who's about to achieve success.

Comment: 'The next big thing' is in the right ballpark.

Comment: *Set to win* is common enough.

Comment: Similar but not quite duplicate as it's about a thing not a person https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298217/more-compelling-way-to-describe-something-as-the-next-big-thing

Answer (score 1):

Budding is close, though more like accumulating steps towards success, like a budding scientist--someone who is on their way to become a scientist.

budding

adjective

```
The definition of budding is something that is just starting to grow or show promise.
```

An example of something that would be described as budding is the new career of a talented person who shows great promise in the field.

Promising is another option that is close.

promising

```
adj.
Likely to develop in a desirable manner.
```

A phrase could be "they are so close they can almost taste it", meaning they are near to achieving success; but they could still miss it, like it could be used as, "they were so close they could almost taste it, too bad though".